# multiply each number from arrays by each other one time only in PHP

Tags: php

i am trying to think of a way in PHP to make that calculation and i don't know where to start any help will be appreciated.
I want to multiply every  combination possible 3 out of array values like

```
[1,2,3,4]

    1*2*3
    1*2*4
    2*3*4
    4*3*1
```

after that, I want the sum of them like
expected result:

6+8+24+12 = 50

Comment: _"i want to multiply each array"_ - Your question only contains one array though? Do you mean that you want to multiply each value in the array?

Comment: Could you provide us with the code you already have?

Comment: i mean each value in the array sorry :)

Comment: This can be done quite easy using two nested for loops. Each runs from 0 to (number of elements - 1), and inside the inner loop, you calculate the multiplication result, but you skip those entries where outer loop index == inner loop index. After the inner loop, you then add this partial result onto your final one. Hint: A good value to _initialize_ the multiplication result before the inner loop, is the _neutral element_ of multiplication.

Comment: check this [solution](https://3v4l.org/uqip5)

Comment: this solution is perfect please post it so i can choose it as solved, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why multiply if you can divide?

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$product = array_product($arr);
$multiples = array_map(function($el) use ($product) { return $product / $el; }, $arr);
// var_dump($multiples); 
// array(4) { [0]=> int(24) [1]=> int(12) [2]=> int(8) [3]=> int(6) }
var_dump(array_sum($multiples));
```

[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/mUv1I).

In short, the idea is that `a * b * c` equal to `a * b * c * d / d`, `a * b * d` is `a * b * c * d / c` etc. The only caveat is that when you work with big numbers, there might be some overflow happening, but that's easy to spot right at `$product` calculation step.

---

Ok, so it turns out there's more to that task than mentioned in description. If that's the case, and you want a generic solution, you might consider creating permutations of all the elements you need first, then calculating the sum of all the multiplications of all the permutations.

Still, for this particular case - 'take pair of elements, multiply them, then calculate the sum' - there's another O(n) solution:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];
$sum = array_sum($arr);
$sum_of_multiples = array_reduce($arr, function($carr, $item) use (&$sum) {
    return $carr + $item * ($sum -= $item);
}, 0);
var_dump($sum_of_multiples); // int(35)
```

[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/UR7f3).

It's based on a simple fact that for each individual element of an array, sum of multiples involving it is simply this element multiplied by the sum of all the other elements.

Comment: it looks very good , what needs change in that code so i can choose 2 out of 4 so i get all combinations possible with 2 numbers instead of 3 , thanks

Comment: It's a bit different task than the one described above, no? If there's too many variables in your task, you might consider calculating permutations first, then just going through them, multiplying and adding them. Still, there's a O(N) solution for case of 2 as well, will add it in a moment.

Comment: thanks Raina but sachin kumara liyanage posted exactly what i needed :) working perfect , thanks to you i got the solution :)